# how can I order a list dynamically in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I try for a todo-list to be able to order the list via a filter so that can i have the list for today the list for tomorrow or the list of the week so i made my task controller able to take request et via the design pattern reposiory i take the request to do the eloquent request :

controller tasks :

```html
class TaskController extends Controller
{

    private $taskRepository;

    public function __construct(TaskRepository $taskRepository)
    {
        $this->taskRepository = $taskRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        if(!empty($request)){
            // dd($request);
            $tasks = $this->taskRepository->all($request);

        }else{
            $tasks = $this->taskRepository->all();
        }

        return view('tasks.index', compact('tasks'));
    }
 }
```

taskrepository :

```html
class TaskRepository implements RepositoryInterface
{
    // model property on class instances
    protected $task;

     // Constructor to bind model to repo
     public function __construct(Task $task)
     {
         $this->task = $task;
     }

    public function all(Request $request)
    {
        $sortBy = 'expired_at';
        $order = Carbon::now();
        $finish = null;


        if($request)
        {
            if($request->has('today'))
            {
                $order = Carbon::today();
                return Task::where($sortBy, $order)->get();
            }

            if($request->has('tomorow')){

                $order = Carbon::tomorrow();
                return Task::where($sortBy, $order)->get();
            }

            if($request->has('week'))
            {

                $order = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
                $finish = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();
                return Task::whereBetween($sortBy, [$order, $finish])->get();

            }


        }else{

            return Task::orderBy('order')->get();
        }
    }
```

to finish in my index i have form using the "get" method :

```html
div>

        <form action="{{ route('tasks.index') }}" class="flex justify-between items-center p-2">
                <div>

                    <select name="orderByDate" id="">
                        @foreach(['today','tomorow', 'week'] as $orderDate)
                            <option value="{{ $orderDate }}">{{ ucfirst($orderDate) }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Filter</button>
                </div>
        </form>

</div>
<ul class="my-5">
    @foreach ($tasks as $task)

        @if($task->order == 0)

        <li class="flex text-red-600 justify-between p-2">
            // task->name
            // task-> date
            // task-> edit
            // task->delete
        </li>
        @else

            <li class="flex justify-between items-center p-2">
                // task->name
              // task-> date
              // task-> edit
              // task->delete
            </li>

        @endif
        @empty
            <p>Pas de tâches aujourd'hui crée en une</p>
        @endforelse
</ul>

@endsection
```

aparrently my foreach doesn't work  with an array  so if anyone have some lead to how should i approch this issue will be a live saver ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for the repository function

```
public function all(Request $request)
{
    $sortBy = 'expired_at';
    $order = Carbon::now();
    $finish = null;


    if($request)
    {
        if($request->has('today'))
        {
            $order = Carbon::today();
            return Task::query()->where($sortBy, $order)->orderBy($sortBy)->get();
        }

        if($request->has('tomorow')){

            $order = Carbon::tomorrow();
            return Task::query()->where($sortBy, $order)->orderBy($sortBy)->get();
        }

        if($request->has('week'))
        {

            $order = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
            $finish = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();
            return Task::query()->whereBetween($sortBy, [$order, $finish])->orderBy($sortBy)->get();

        }


    }else{

        return Task::query()->orderBy($sortBy)->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i try  but now i have a error like :"ViewException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Users/{name}/code/todo_list/resources/views/tasks/index.blade.php) " and i don't know why because it's works before every time i do this kind of config in the repository  i have an error

Comment: @forelse ($tasks as $task) >@if($task->order == 0)>@if($task->status) it seem having a problem with the forelse who works perfectly otherwise

Comment: did you pass parameter in request ( any one of ['today','tomorow', 'week']) ??

Comment: i re-edit the view usually it' not that charged it's seem to have probleme with the forelse

Comment: Please try answer code again. I have made some changes

Comment: still the same issue in the view : "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"